# Aumentar y disminuir producto cesta (PHP, JS, MYSQL)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código que simula una cesta de la compra

```
if(isset($_SESSION['carrito']) && count($_SESSION['carrito']) > 0)
    {
      foreach($_SESSION['carrito'] as $producto) {
        $cantidad = $producto['cantidad'];
        $id_producto = $producto['id_producto'];
        $datos_producto = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id='".$id_producto."'");
        $row_prod = mysqli_fetch_array($datos_producto, MYSQLI_ASSOC);?>
        <input type="button" value="+"/><input type="button" value="-"/><?php echo "".$cantidad."x - ".$row_prod['nombre']." - <a href='carrito.php?eliminar=".$id_producto."'><u>Eliminar</u></a></p>";
        $_SESSION['total_carrito'] += $cantidad * $row_prod['precio'];
        }
    }
```

`$cantidad` es la variable que almacena la cantidad de ese producto que deseas comprar. Me gustaría saber como podría hacer que con los botones de + y - que tengo creados, poder disminuir o aumentar la cantidad de cosas que quiero de cada producto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con javaScript solo debes ponerle un evento onclick a tus botones de `+` y `-`, mantienes una variable global que sería tu cantidad de productos y aumenta o decrementa tu variable de cantidad al final del evento solo debes pasarle el resultado en donde se muestra tu cantidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu codigo tiene errores. Aquí tienes un código funcional.

Básicamente:

- agregue datos de prueba y los iguale a la variable de `sesion`
- Agregue una etiqueta `from` para utilizar el metodo `POST`
- Asigne un nombre al boton `sumar`
- Asigne un nombre al boton `restar`
- Verifico que botón han hecho click.

```html
<?php
session_start();


//verifico si el usuario dio click en el boton sumar
if(isset($_POST["sumar"])){
    $identificadorFila = $_POST["sumar"];
    $_SESSION["carrito"][$identificadorFila]["cantidad"]++ ;

}
//verifico si el usuario dio click en el boton restar
if(isset($_POST["restar"])){
    $identificadorFila = $_POST["restar"];
    $_SESSION["carrito"][$identificadorFila]["cantidad"]-- ;
}


//defino este arreglo para tener datos para el ejemplo (esto deberia ser dinamico)
$carrito = [];
$carrito[] = [ "cantidad" => 1 ,"id_producto" => 1, "row_prod" => "leche" ,"precio" => 10];
$carrito[] = [ "cantidad" => 1 ,"id_producto" => 2, "row_prod" => "huevos" ,"precio" => 5];
$carrito[] = [ "cantidad" => 1 ,"id_producto" => 3, "row_prod" => "jamon" ,"precio" => 20];
$carrito[] = [ "cantidad" => 1 ,"id_producto" => 4, "row_prod" => "sal" ,"precio" => 1];

//relleno la variable de session carroto on los datos de prueba
if(!isset($_SESSION["carrito"])) $_SESSION["carrito"] = $carrito;
else $carrito = $_SESSION["carrito"];



$total = 0;

echo "<form method='POST'>";
    foreach($carrito as $k => $producto) {
            $cantidad = $producto['cantidad'];
            $id_producto = $producto['id_producto'];
            $precio= $producto["cantidad"];
            $nombre= $producto["row_prod"];
            $precio= $producto["precio"];
            $preciofila = $precio * $cantidad;
           
            echo " <button name='sumar' type='submit' value='$k'> + </button>";
            echo " <button name='restar' type='submit' value='$k'> - </button>";

            echo $cantidad. "x - " .$nombre. "(". $preciofila  ."$)"." - <a href='carrito.php?eliminar=".$id_producto."'><u>Eliminar</u></a></p>";
            $total += $precio * $cantidad;
    }

echo "<p>Total = $total $</p>"   ; 
echo "</from>";

?>
```

Cosas a validar:

- Que no pueda restar productos cuando la cantidad es 0